In what sense bootstrapping allows you to bypass certain assumptions of the linear regression method?
I was reading a question about parameters estimation with a small sample, and the author asked if bootstrapping was a way to overcome the lack of power of the study.
Which is not the case.
But somebody wrote about the content of my question , so i got curious.
In what sense bootstrapping allows you to  bypass at least some assumptions of the linear regression method (Gauss-Markov)?

Calculations of confidence intervals and p-values via t-tests and F-tests in linear regression models are based on the assumption that repeated samples of the coefficient estimates follow a (multivariate) normal distribution. In linear regression, that's assured  if the requirements of the Gauss-Markov Theorem hold and the error terms further have a normal distribution. The fitting procedure provides an estimate of that normal sampling distribution of the coefficient estimates.
With large enough samples, the Central Limit Theorem can lead (asymptotically) to a normal sampling distribution of linear regression coefficient estimates. In regression models fit by maximum likelihood (e.g., generalized linear models), the coefficient estimates also have a normal distribution in the limit of large sample sizes. It's not always clear, however, how large a sample is large enough to come close to the ideal normal distribution.
Bootstrapping lets the data directly tell you the sampling distribution of the regression coefficients, providing empirical estimates of confidence intervals and p-values. You don't need to assume a normal distribution of error terms or of coefficient estimates. Insofar as bootstrap resampling from a data set represents taking the original sample from the underlying population (the fundamental bootstrap assumption), the distribution of coefficient estimates calculated from the same model fit to multiple bootstrap samples is a direct estimate of the sampling distribution of the regression coefficients, the variance-covariance matrix.
The reliability of that estimate, however, can depend on many details of the data and the model. In particular, small data samples might not adequately represent the underlying population. This page discusses several situations in which bootstrapping can be unreliable.
